# Confusing behaviour when handling exceptions in combination with using

Tags: c#, exception, unit-of-work

## Question

I am currently implementing a UOW pattern and have come upon a weird behaviour for exception handling, which is hindering my progress.

My UOW structure looks the following:

```cs
public abstract class UnitOfWork : IDisposable {
    public virtual void Save() {
        if (_madeAction) ThrowInvalidCall();
        _madeAction = true;
    }
    public virtual void Cancel() {
        if (_madeAction) ThrowInvalidCall();
        _madeAction = true;
    }
    public virtual void Dispose() {
        if (!_madeAction) {
            Cancel();
            throw new UnitOfWorkAborted("Unit of work was aborted and automatically rolled back!");
        }
    }
    private bool _madeAction = false;
    private void ThrowInvalidCall() => throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(Save)} or {nameof(Cancel)} can only be called once in a unit of work!");
}

[Serializable]
public class UnitOfWorkAborted : Exception {
    public UnitOfWorkAborted() { }
    public UnitOfWorkAborted(string message) : base(message) { }
    public UnitOfWorkAborted(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
}

public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory {
    UnitOfWork CreateNew();
}
```

I am expecting to use this UOW as follows:

```cs
try {
    using (var uow = uowFactory.CreateNew()) {
        // Do some operation
        throw new InvalidCastException(); // Oh, something went wrong.
        uow.Save();
    }
} catch (UnitOfWorkAborted ex) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

The problem obviously is, that the excpetion will never be handled by my try/catch clause as it only handles *UnitOfWorkAborted* which is only thrown after the *InvalidCastException*.

My question is, is there any way I can use my UOW how I expect it to work? (I'd like to replicate this behaviour -> [TransactionScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope))

I want to keep the code for creating a UOW and managing it as simple as possible.

If possible, I would love to even have the actual exception as the inner exception of *UnitOfWorkAborted*.

## Observations/Attempts

###### 1. Instead of catching the *UnitOfWorkAborted* I can catch all Exceptions and cast it to *UnitOfWorkAborted*.

```
try {
    using (var uow = uowFactory.CreateNew()) {
        throw new InvalidCastException();
        uow.Save();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    UnitOfWorkAborted uowEx = ex as UnitOfWorkAborted;
    if (uowEx is null) throw ex;

    // Handle exception
}
```

- Cons:

  - I will need to cast the exception to *UnitOfWorkAborted* and this adds code that should be avoidable because:
  - What is try/catch then even for when not for specifying which exception to handle? This approach just feels.. ugh.

###### 2. Add a catch clause for *Exception*.

```
try {
    using (var uow = uowFactory.CreateNew()) {
        throw new InvalidCastException();
        uow.Save();
    }
} catch (UnitOfWorkAborted ex) {
    // Handle exception
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

I discovered this through experimentation, it works perfectly fine. Would it be possible to get a side-explanation on the details for why this works, I would be incredibly interested to know. Either way, the syntax is incredibly misleading, even worse than with the first attempt, and this is no option of course, just, look at it.

**Are these two attempts really my only options on solving this problem?**

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1065#dispose-methods "A System.IDisposable.Dispose method should not throw an exception. Dispose is often called as part of the cleanup logic in a finally clause. Therefore, explicitly throwing an exception from Dispose forces the user to add exception handling inside the finally clause."

Comment: Thank you for the information, I did not know that! How am I then even able to replicate TransactionScope's behaviour? This is not directed at you, but I do not understand why I got downvoted, in my eyes the question is loud and clear.

Comment: Rather than a using block, you could force the caller to do their work in a callback `uowFactory.Run(uow => {});`. That way you can catch and throw with an inner exception. Or just not throw. If you expect every caller to try and save at the end, an exception should be the only way to avoid calling save.

Comment: That is a great suggestion! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the callback method suggested by Jeremy Lakeman in the comments, which ended up working perfectly fine, with the bonus of catching inner exceptions.